# How do you create optgroups in react-select v2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to have optgroups in my react-select list, but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.  I have the following structure, which I pulled from a comment in https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/59:

```
render() {
  const options = [
    {
      label: "Group 1",
      children: [
        { label: "Group 1, option 1", value: "value_1" },
        { label: "Group 1, option 2", value: "value_2" }
      ]
    },
    { label: "A root option", value: "value_3" },
    { label: "Another root option", value: "value_4" }
  ];
  return <Select options={options} />
}
```

I expect "Group 1" to be an optgroup, with options 1 and 2 as children.  Instead, "Group 1" just appears as a regular option.  Does anyone know what the correct key is, within "Group 1", to turn it into an optgroup?

I've already tried "children", and "values", but to no effect.

Comment: It is actually documented at https://react-select.com/props#groupheading under GroupType.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

**options** is the magic key:

```
render() {
  const options = [
    {
      label: "Group 1",
      options: [
        { label: "Group 1, option 1", value: "value_1" },
        { label: "Group 1, option 2", value: "value_2" }
      ]
    },
    { label: "A root option", value: "value_3" },
    { label: "Another root option", value: "value_4" }
  ];
  return <Select options={options} />
}
```

This renders the way that I expect.

Comment: According to the docs I linked to in the OP comment, this is still valid; was there a specific thing that wasn't working?

Comment: how can I get selected group label and label and value of option selected ?

Comment: I mean to say how can I get "Group 1" if I select Group 1,option 1

Comment: @Kalyan If your code has the items categorized for the select, I would think you could easily detect to which group an item belongs, outside the context of react-select. In any case, if you still have trouble, you should always ask in a new question.