# How to set value of react-select with grouped options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

How do you set the value with javascript of a [react-select](https://github.com/jedwatson/react-select) component with grouped options?
Grouped options as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503732/how-do-you-create-optgroups-in-react-select-v2).

Edit in reply to comment by @Tholle

I did not mention that I'm using Typescript, because questions tend to get less answers I think.

This is how I'm using the component:

```
<Select
    value={this.state.Industry}
    options={this.industryOptions}
    onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange("industry", e)}
></Select>
```

Where industryOptions is of this type:

```
industryOptions: Array<{label: string, options: Array<{label: string, value: string}>}>
```

E.g:

```
label: "Automotive"
options: Array(3)
    0: {label: "Car brand", value: "77"}
    1: {label: "Car dealer", value: "76"}
    2: {label: "Other", value: "75"}
```

When selecting an option in the dropdown this.state.Industry changes, but nothing happens with the Select component when this.state.Industry is changed.

Comment: Could you include the desired behaviour and what you have tried so far in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question for future reference.
I realized "value" should be of the same type as an option. I.e. an object of this type {label: string, value: string}, not a string.
So I figuered I needed to search for an option that had the same value. This is in the render function of my component (parent of Select):

```
let indystryValue: {value: string, label: string}
let prospect: {value: string, label: string} | undefined;
this.industryOptions.forEach((io) => {
    prospect = io.options.find((o) => o.value == this.state!.measurementBasics!.Industry.toString());
    if(prospect !== undefined){
        indystryValue = prospect;
    }
});
```

...and put that in the Select like this:

`<Select value={indystryValue!} ...`

Although I got this compile error it is working:
[ts]
Type '{ value: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ValueType<{ label: string; options: { label: string; value: string; }[]; }>'.
  Type '{ value: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ label: string; options: { label: string; value: string; }[]; }[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type '{ value: string; label: string; }'. [2322]
Select.d.ts(202, 3): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly>'
(JSX attribute) value?: ValueType<{ label: string; options: { label: string; value: string; }[]; }>